# Deployment of files to Virtual Machines

Tags: deployment

During our development process the developers do code modifications, compile the code and need to deploy it on a remote machine and test it or debug it remotely.

There are manual steps that are usually needed - stop one or more services, copy the compiled files to specific place in the destination machine and other steps (maybe delete some folder etc.)

I was wondering if there is a tool that as input gets IP of remote machine and predefined steps (stop service, copy local files to remote machine etc) - and just do autmatic deployment for the developer? I'd like to automate this tiring process a bit...

Thanks.

Comment: We just use MSBUILD for this.

Answer (score 0):

[Ant](http://ant.apache.org/index.html) is a common tool for such tasks in Java development. You can use ant to compile your code, use an scp task to copy your binaries to a server and run scripts on that server. The configuration is done by XML and is pretty easy. You should google or search on stackoverflow for some examples.

Comment: thanks - does it include also service up and down? in our company we use also c# so I'm looking for more generic solution

Comment: @user1025852: You can run any scripts on the server so stopping and starting services is possible. You can use ant also for building C#: http://ant.apache.org/antlibs/dotnet/ But I haven't used ant in this context yet.

Answer (score 0):

I use [rundeck](http://rundeck.org/) to control my deployments. I like it's simplicity and the fact that all that's required is SSH access to my servers, enabling me to upload files, and run whatever scripts I require.

It has a simple XML configuration file listing the servers in my network. This makes it really easy to integrate with other CM tools.

For windows deployments you're going to require an SSH implementation installed on each node, or a more complicated deployment tool.